# How can I tripple-boot via my Mac? Help install Linux? I already got OS X Lion and Windows and 30GB unpartitioned space reserved for Linux

Tags: linux, mac, multi-boot, refit, easybcd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Triple boot (OS X/Win/Linux) via rEFIt doesn't work - Linux not visible in rEFIt](https://superuser.com/questions/316012/triple-boot-os-x-win-linux-via-refit-doesnt-work-linux-not-visible-in-refit)

I would really love to triple-boot on my MacBook Pro. (Not with Virtual machines!!)
I already configured Mac OS X Lion and Windows 7 (via BootCamp.)
So current situation is:

- [200 MB EFI partition (I suppose)]
- 430 GB Partition: Mac OS X Lion
- [650 MB Lion Recovery Partition] -> I don't want to remove it
- 30 GB Partition: Windows 7 Ultimate
- 30 GB free, unpartitioned space - reserved for Linux - created during the installation of Win7.

It doesn't matter to me if its Ubuntu or Mint Linux. I did a few tries installing Linux myself, I already installed it but could not boot into it. (It wasn't in the EFI, nor in rEFIt, when I booted my Mac.)

I just can't do it alone, so **will someone write me a guide** (or send a link to one- although I Googled and found nothing for Lion)? Also, booted from the Linux LiveCD, how should I install it- how should I partition my drives etc. I tried everything I knew and didn't really worked out for me.

What I tried:

- **TRY NO 1.** After I couldn't find the Linux partition on the screen (when you hold ALT when starting up), only the Macintosh HD and Windows, I did a search and installed rEFIt. When I successfully got the rEFIt boot menu (thats how it's called?), I still didn't see my Linux partition (neither the SWAP space nor the ext4.) I googled and found that rEFIt shows only the MBR partition table (am I right?.) So using the rEFIt Partition Inspector I inspected my drive. I found that the Linux drive ISN'T in the MBR table... This was a dead end, cause I didn't find how to edit the MBR. I formatted the Linux partitions using Disk Utility, so they are "free space".
- **TRY NO 2.** I read about creating a bootscheme like: Macintosh HD - Windows, and if the user chose Windows, he could choose Windows or Linux. If the user chose Macintosh HD, Lion would normally boot up. I installed EasyBCD on my Win7. When I wanted to add the Linux partition, so I went to Add/Remove entries in EasyBCD and then Linux. I chose GRUB2 (although I don't really got what it is), cause I read that Mint 11 has GRUB2). I saved the settings and rebooted. Then it rEFIt I chose Windows and then I chose Linux. For a while nothing happened, then it threw me into a command line with "grub>" at the beginning of the line. I didn't know what to do on, so I again deleted the Linux partitions using Disk Utility. Now I have the 30GB free space again. I also uninstalled rEFIt and EasyBCD, so I have a fresh start.

Could someone **please** write me what I should do after I boot from the Linux LiveCD? How should I proceed my installation?

Thanks a lot in advance!
**I really hope this gets answered, but its a pretty tough one, I think :(**

Comment: Please don't post duplicates of the same problem. You can always go back to your previous question, [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/316012/edit) it and supply more details.

Comment: the question is different ;) I hope it wont be removed...

Comment: Your essential problem is that you want triple boot your Mac, right? This is exactly the same problem. You're only asking for a different way to resolve it, but it would be better to supply all necessary information you have in **one question**. Your chances of having it answered are better then, and future visitors will also benefit from this.

Comment: guess your right :( but the bad thing is- still no answer

Comment: You asked your other question 11 hours ago which isn't that long -- you just might want to give it some time. If you want I can help you to reword your previous question!

Comment: Ubuntu has a special version for mac hardware, I blogged about this a few years ago. https://spuder.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/macbook-pro-cant-boot-ubuntu-disk/

Comment: I also believe that this question is different. This question can't install linux, the other question linux is installed, but grub is misconfigured.